# How to insert non repeated values when I click previous button in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created online exam application (web based) in asp.net c#. In my application

- The first form contains a drop down list for
  tests & a start button.

  When i select a particular test from the dropdownlist and then clicking the start button ,it goes to the next page.
- this page contains one label for
  question, radiobuttonlist for
  answers, next & previous button.

In the first form :the click event of the start button, i have created non repeated random values (for question ids) i.e stored in array.
when it redirects to another page then 1st question from that array will display with answers & after clicking next button next question will appear, here i have inserted selected values(answers selected in radiobuttonlist) by user in database to calculate score.**The Problem is**  when  clicking the previous button and then selecting another answer then it reinserts the record again as i want to update that value, not the repeated value. I have written the following code for this but it doesn't work. Here

```
if (result != DBNull.Value)
```

this condition doesn't work correctly as i want to check that value exists or not.

Please help me?

```
 if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]) <= 7)
        {
            //a is the array of random values where Counter is my counter start value=1
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT selected from Sel_Ans WHERE Quid=" + a[Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]) - 1] + "", sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();
            var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result != DBNull.Value)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Sel_Ans Set Selected=@Selected WHERE Quid=" + a[Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]) - 1] + "", sqlconn);
                SqlParameter Selected = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Selected", SqlDbType.Int, 50);

                Selected.Value = rb;
                sqlconn.Close();
                sqlconn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlconn.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                int t = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]);

                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Sel_Ans VALUES ('1', @Quid, @Selected, '1')", sqlconn);
                SqlParameter Quid = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Quid", SqlDbType.Int, 50);
                Quid.Value = a[t - 2];

                SqlParameter Selected = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Selected", SqlDbType.Int, 50);
                Selected.Value = rb;
                sqlconn.Close();
                sqlconn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlconn.Close();
            }
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: this condition doesn't work correctly as i want to check that value exists or not??

Comment: what you mean, and 
`if (result != DBNull.Value)
`
contains your code or not??

Comment: i want selected values to be inserted but if that value already exists then update should occur not the insertion of new value

Comment: when you debug what is the value of result? theoretically that check should be fine. Personally though having just done something similar i put the update/insert in a stored procedure which does the check.

Comment: its giving true value of result but it should be false as there is no record in my table that means it should insert that value

Comment: just to clarify what is the exact value of "var result"? 0, 1, null, true, false?

Comment: when i debug then var result value gives null and if condition gives true value so it goes to update query instead it should go to the insert query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the result should indicate whether it inserts new record or not( duplicate key),if not Update the record instead.

**EDIT:**

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Count(*)from Sel_Ans WHERE Quid=" + a[Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]) - 1] + "", sqlconn);

            sqlconn.Open();
            int result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result != 0)
```

Comment: but its not happening, it goes to the (true condition) update statement instead it should go to the (else) insert statement

Comment: i suppose your table have a primary key. so the default case that you insert a new record (and the effect will stored in the result variable), if the record is already inserted ( primary key violation), then it will update instead.

Comment: When i assign primary key then it doesnt work because when i click previous & select new answer then it inserts new record of that question id(selected value should be updated here) thats why i am checking whether that value exists or not if exists then update that value if not exists then insert those values. initially this table i kept as a blank because i passed delete query at last so when i run the project then that table is blank. Problem is that this code inserts new record for that question id(with new selected answer) so how i can solve this problem

Comment: i think u have some problem in the database design.any way as u can do the following: As Edited in my answer.

Comment: count(*) wil give total value but how i can find here whether that value exists or not my table(SelAns having fields: Tid,qid,selected(ans selected by user) and marks (marks per question)

Comment: no the Count(*) will return the number of rows. so if there is an answer to the question before, this query will return 1 so u can update if there is no answer the query will return 0 so u can insert the new record.

Comment: Its right that it will check number of rows ,if values not inside the table it will inserts that value for the question but this code is written in next button so when i click next button & then  previous button & suppose i changed value here then it will inserts new selected value for the same question id. so i want to check whether that question id exists or not, if exists then pass update query & if not then insert that record

Comment: you can make the same check in the Previous button. but i recommend you to make the design more clear and concise , How? by adding one more button in addition to the `Next` & `Previous` buttons, let call it the `Confirm button` , this button will be used to confirm the user answer, so you can put your checks in this button to make decision about inserting new answer or just update existing one.and the `Next & the Previous buttons` ,the main purpose of them ,just get the next and the previous question.